# Single dimension array to multidimension (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm a noob at programming so this might be very easy. I have a textfile on my computer with lines. Each line have *exactly* one string (with two words) *always* seperated by a white space before there is a new line such as:

```
asd qwe
qwe zxc
fgh yui
```

and so on. I can get that textfile just fine into a single dimensional array by using following code:

```
$file = file("file.txt");
```

Now my problem: how do i turn this single dimensional array into a multidimensional array so that line one (asd qwe) will be entered into the multidimensional array so that the key (its's first right?) is "asd" and value is "qwe"?

There is absolutely no need to have any fancy coding for this nor does it have to be fast. Just "simple" so i understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = array();
foreach($file as $line)
{
    $data = explode(" ", $line);
    $array[$data[0]] = $data[1];
}
```

Will give you this:

```
array(
    [asd] => qwe
    [qwe] => zxc
    [fgh] => yui
)
```

And this:

```
$array = array();
foreach($file as $line)
{
    $data = explode(" ", $line);
    $array[] = array($data[0], $data[1]);
}
```

will give you this:

```
array(
    [0] => array([0] => asd [1] => qwe)
    [1] => array([0] => qwe [1] => zxc)
    [2] => array([0] => fgh [1] => yui)
)
```

Comment: That was pretty damn fast and very helpful reply. Thanks a lot! :)